# Find and replace a string when that line contains another string in VIM

Tags: vim, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a word or string on each line in a file if it contains another string in vim.  For example, given a file containing:

```
Hello World Test
This is a Hello Test
World This Test Hello a
```

I want to replace Test with Apple where that line contains the words Hello and World.  I would use the search statement to find the lines that contain Hello and World (in no either order).  But how would I go about coming up with a substitute for Test on those lines.

Example Find Statement:

```
/\(Hello.*World\)\|\(World.*Hello\)
```

Example Updated file

```
Hello World Apple
This is a Hello Test
World This Apple Hello a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global) command for that:

```
:g/Hello.*World\|World.*Hello/s/Test/Apple/g
```

Here we run the substitution command `s/Test/Apple/g` on all lines where `Hello.*World\|World.*Hello` matches.

Comment: Perfect, this did exactly what I wanted.  It won't let me select an answer yet but once it does I'll do that.  I appreciate it.